# Referencing self in a callback

Tags: nativescript

My code is:

```
class myclass observable.Observable
{
    let label = "test";

    navigatingTo(args: observable.EventData)
    {
        target.on( "name", this._callback );
    }

    _callback ( eventData )
    {    
         console.log( this.label);
    }
}
```

When I print out this.label in the callback - "this" object is not the object that I expect - which I think should be the myclass instance.

I've got a separate method for the callback because I'm also calling .off() later and need a reference to the method (as opposed to anonymous function)

Comment: Can you post the complete code of your example (XML too) - it would help get the whole picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a third argument when subscribing with `on()`. The third argument will be used as a context(this) for the callback. So probably you want to do:

```
target.on("name", this._callback, this);
```